# How to start activities depending on the database conditions?

Tags: android, sqlite, if-statement

I’m trying to write an Android app with SQLite Database. I have 4 activites.  I want to start these activities depending on specific cases in my database. 
This is my Database schema:
 [image]
In the current situation;

```
…

listem.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Intent myintentGameA = new Intent(view.getContext(),GameA.class);

            startActivity(myintentGameA);

    }
});
 ...
```

I have 5 list items as you can see in my db. With the code above, when I click the first list item in my program I can start my GameA activity and I can see the numbers

> 2,17,24,25,3...

I want to create my other intents like this;

```
Intent myintentGameB = new Intent(view.getContext(),GameB.class);
Intent myintentGameC = new Intent(view.getContext(),GameC.class);
Intent myintentGameD = new Intent(view.getContext(),GameD.class);
```

and when I click to second list item I want to start myinentGameC activity and see the numbers

> 7, 14 ,23, 27, 30,..

and so on... I could not write the proper if else condition with the cursor functions. I think it should be something like this:

- move cursor to somewhere
- check if GameA column is null
- if it is not null, start myintentGameA activity
- if it is null, check if GameB column is null
- if it is not null, start myintentGameB activity
- if it is null, check if GameCcolumn is null
- if it is not null, start myintentGameC activity
- if it is null, check if GameD column is null
- if it is not null, start myintentGameD activity

Any help would be appreciated thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to have an SQL query do the work. For example the following query:-

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN gamea IS NOT NULL THEN 'gamea' 
        WHEN gameb IS NOT NULL then 'gameb'
        WHEN gamec IS NOt NULL then 'gamec'
        WHEN gamed IS NOT NULL then 'gamed'
    END AS game,
    CASE 
        WHEN gamea IS NOT NULL THEN gamea
        WHEN gameb IS NOT NULL THEN gameb
        WHEN gamec IS NOT NULL THEN gamec
        WHEN gamed IS NOT NULL then gamed
    END AS gamevalue
FROM gamestart
WHERE id = 1
```

(where the **1** in WHERE id = 1 would be the id of the row obtained when the list item is clicked)

This would then return (via a Cursor) :-

**"gamea"   "2,17,24,25,3..."** (game? in a column called **game**, values in a column called **gamestart**)

So you extract the game that is to be started and the values to be used.

All combinations (i.e. omitting the WHERE clause) are :-

[image]

To use the query in Android you could have a method such as :-

```
public Cursor getGameToStart(long id) {
    String game_column = "CASE " +
            "WHEN gamea IS NOT NULL THEN 'gamea' " +
            "WHEN gameb IS NOT NULL then 'gameb' " +
            "WHEN gamec IS NOT NULL then 'gamec' " +
            "WHEN gamed IS NOT NULL then 'gamed' " +
            "END AS " + TEMPCOL_GAME;
    String gamevalues_column = "CASE " +
            "WHEN gamea IS NOT NULL THEN gamea " +
            "WHEN gameb IS NOT NULL THEN gameb " +
            "WHEN gamec IS NOT NULL THEN gamec " +
            "WHEN gamed IS NOT NULL then gamed " +
            "END AS " + TEMPCOL_GAMEVALUES;
    String[] columns = new String[]{game_column,gamevalues_column};
    String whereclause = COL_ID + "=?";
    String[] whereargs = new String[]{String.valueOf(id)};
    return mDB.query(TBL_GAMESTART,columns,whereclause,whereargs,null,null,null);
}
```

- mDB is the SQLiteDatabase
- COL_ID is the id column
- TEMPCOL_GAME is the column to be included in the cursor (game)
- TEMPCOL_GAMEVALUES is the column to be included in the cursor (gamevalues)

The following was used to test the above (replicating selecting all list items 1-5) :-

```
SO49863106DBHelper dbhlpr = new SO49863106DBHelper(this);
for (long i=1; i < 6; i++) {
    Cursor csr = dbhlpr.getGameToStart(i);
    Log.d("GAMEINFO","Game Number = " + String.valueOf(i) + " Rows Extracted = " + String.valueOf(csr.getCount()));
    while (csr.moveToNext()) {
        Log.d("GAMEINFO",
                "\n\t Game is " + csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(SO49863106DBHelper.TEMPCOL_GAME)) +
                        " Values are " + csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(SO49863106DBHelper.TEMPCOL_GAMEVALUES))
        );
    }
    csr.close();
}
```

The resultant output being :-

```
04-16 21:57:49.051 1377-1377/? D/GAMEINFO: Game Number = 1 Rows Extracted = 1
         Game is gamea Values are 2,17,24,25,3...
    Game Number = 2 Rows Extracted = 1
         Game is gamec Values are 7,14,23,27,30,...
04-16 21:57:49.055 1377-1377/? D/GAMEINFO: Game Number = 3 Rows Extracted = 1
         Game is gamed Values are 4,11,21,27,45,...
    Game Number = 4 Rows Extracted = 1
         Game is gamec Values are 2,5,23,47,51,...
    Game Number = 5 Rows Extracted = 1
04-16 21:57:49.059 1377-1377/? D/GAMEINFO:   Game is gamed Values are 7,10,17,21,33,...
```

The Databasehelper **SO49863106DBHelper.java** used in the above was :-

```
public class SO49863106DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DBNAME = "games";
    public static final int DBVERSION = 1;

    public static final String TBL_GAMESTART = "gamestart";
    public static final String COL_ID = BaseColumns._ID;
    public static final String COL_GAMEA = "gamea";
    public static final String COL_GAMEB = "gameb";
    public static final String COL_GAMEC = "gamec";
    public static final String COL_GAMED = "gamed";

    public static final String TEMPCOL_GAME = "game";
    public static final String TEMPCOL_GAMEVALUES = "gamevalues";

    SQLiteDatabase mDB;

    public SO49863106DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DBNAME, null, DBVERSION);
        mDB = this.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    @Override

    //Table Create SQL
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String crtsql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TBL_GAMESTART +
                "(" +
                COL_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
                COL_GAMEA + " TEXT," +
                COL_GAMEB + " TEXT," +
                COL_GAMEC + " TEXT, " +
                COL_GAMED + " TEXT" +
                ")";
        //Insert the Data SQL
        String insertsql = "INSERT INTO " + TBL_GAMESTART +
                "(" + COL_GAMEA + "," + COL_GAMEB + "," + COL_GAMEC + "," + COL_GAMED + ") VALUES" +
                "('2,17,24,25,3...',null,null,null)," +
                "(null,null,'7,14,23,27,30,...',null)," +
                "(null,null,null,'4,11,21,27,45,...')," +
                "(null,null,'2,5,23,47,51,...',null)," +
                "(null,null,null,'7,10,17,21,33,...')"
                ;
        db.execSQL(crtsql); // Create the table
        db.execSQL(insertsql); //add the data
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }

    public Cursor getGameToStart(long id) {
        String game_column = "CASE " +
                "WHEN gamea IS NOT NULL THEN 'gamea' " +
                "WHEN gameb IS NOT NULL then 'gameb' " +
                "WHEN gamec IS NOT NULL then 'gamec' " +
                "WHEN gamed IS NOT NULL then 'gamed' " +
                "END AS " + TEMPCOL_GAME;
        String gamevalues_column = "CASE " +
                "WHEN gamea IS NOT NULL THEN gamea " +
                "WHEN gameb IS NOT NULL THEN gameb " +
                "WHEN gamec IS NOT NULL THEN gamec " +
                "WHEN gamed IS NOT NULL then gamed " +
                "END AS " + TEMPCOL_GAMEVALUES;
        String[] columns = new String[]{game_column,gamevalues_column};
        String whereclause = COL_ID + "=?";
        String[] whereargs = new String[]{String.valueOf(id)};
        return mDB.query(TBL_GAMESTART,columns,whereclause,whereargs,null,null,null);
    }
}
```